# ServiceActivator/Poller seems to ignore Trigger

Tags: spring-integration

I am using SpringBoot 1.4.4.RELEASE with Brixton.SR6. I am using SpringIntegration with JMS and RabbitMQ.

I have got a JMS-backed queue defined as:

```
<int-jms:channel id="actionInstructionTransformed" queue-name="Action.FieldJmsBackup" message-driven="false" />
```

I have got a default poller defined as:

```
<bean id="customPeriodicTrigger" class="uk.gov.ons.ctp.response.kirona.drs.utility.CustomPeriodicTrigger" />

<bean id="customTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="${container.threads}" />
</bean>

<int:poller id="customPoller" default="true" trigger="customPeriodicTrigger" task-executor="customTaskExecutor" max-messages-per-poll="${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}" error-channel="drsGatewayPollerError">
    <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</int:poller>
```

My CustomPeriodicTrigger implements org.springframework.scheduling.Trigger. I have overriden public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext). In my logs, I can see that nextExecutionTime is invoked constantly and it outputs the time now. The service activator processes which is good. Then at some stage, in nextExecutionTime, I set the next execution time to a date in the future as I want to pause the processing from the JMS queue. In the logs, I can see that nextExecutionTime outputs my date in the future and then it is no more invoked until the future date is reached.

The code for CustomPeriodicTrigger is below:

```
@Slf4j
@Data
public class CustomPeriodicTrigger implements Trigger {

    @Autowired
    private PollerConfig pollerConfig;

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date earliestActiveDate = provideEarliestActiveDate(currentDate);
        log.debug("earliestActiveDate is {}", earliestActiveDate);

        Date result = null;
        if (earliestActiveDate != null) {
            result = new Date(earliestActiveDate.getTime() + pollerConfig.getInitialDelay());
        } else {
            if (triggerContext.lastScheduledExecutionTime() == null) {
                result = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + pollerConfig.getInitialDelay());
            } else {
                if (pollerConfig.isFixedRate()) {
                    result = new Date(triggerContext.lastScheduledExecutionTime().getTime() +
                            pollerConfig.getFixedDelay());
                } else {
                    result = new Date(triggerContext.lastCompletionTime().getTime() +
                            pollerConfig.getFixedDelay());
                }
            }
        }

        log.debug("result is {}", result);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * This returns null if the current date is active, ie outside of support hours.
     * If the current date is within support hours, it returns the earliest active date.
     *
     * @param date the current date
     * @return aDate
     */
    public Date provideEarliestActiveDate(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dateHours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int dateMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        int supportHourStart = pollerConfig.getSupportHourStart();
        int supportMinuteStart = pollerConfig.getSupportMinuteStart();
        int supportHourEnd = pollerConfig.getSupportHourEnd();

        if (dateHours < supportHourStart || dateHours >= supportHourEnd) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (dateMinutes < supportMinuteStart) {
                return null;
            } else {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, supportHourEnd);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                return calendar.getTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It goes with the below which is in my application.yml:

```
  poller:
  fixedDelay: 100
  fixedRate: false
  initialDelay: 1000
  maxMessagesPerPoll: 1
  supportHourStart: 11
  supportMinuteStart: 31
  supportHourEnd: 18
```

The problem is that in the meantime, if I have got messages queued on Action.FieldJmsBackup, they are processed.

My service activator is defined as: `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "actionInstructionTransformed", poller = @Poller(value = "customPoller"))
  public final void processInstruction(final ActionInstruction instruction) {`

I have turned debugging on for org.springframework.integration and when a message is processed despite the poller saying that it should not, I can see in the logs:

```
2017-03-15 11:30:40.068 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6e821210] (actionInstructionReceiverImpl.processInstruction.serviceActivator.handler)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=uk.gov.ons.ctp.response.action.message.instruction.ActionInstruction@1ce9e8d6, headers={jms_destination=RMQDestination{destinationName='Action.Field', queue(permanent)', amqpExchangeName='jms.durable.queues', amqpRoutingKey='Action.Field', amqpQueueName='Action.Field'}, X-Message-Sent=true, messageSent=true, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1489053876187, spanTraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, spanId=74113b330ce8133e, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=74113b330ce8133e, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, id=5c429c04-1df8-6197-42dc-45236ec4a288, HANDLER=Field, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:9a2d4ca0-e173-4725-a2eb-34328c4160f7, timestamp=1489054627940}]
2017-03-15 11:30:40.068 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.t.PseudoTransactionManager         : Initiating transaction commit
2017-03-15 11:30:40.148 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.t.PseudoTransactionManager         : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2017-03-15 11:30:40.149 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate   : Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: com.rabbitmq.jms.client.RMQSession@345df5df
2017-03-15 11:30:40.166 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.integration.jms.PollableJmsChannel   : postReceive on channel 'actionInstructionTransformed', message: GenericMessage [payload=uk.gov.ons.ctp.response.action.message.instruction.ActionInstruction@1d71b5e7, headers={jms_destination=RMQDestination{destinationName='Action.Field', queue(permanent)', amqpExchangeName='jms.durable.queues', amqpRoutingKey='Action.Field', amqpQueueName='Action.Field'}, X-Message-Sent=true, messageSent=true, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1489053876220, spanTraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, spanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, id=fc05c4e2-5c8c-783b-ccbc-e9f46d662ff7, HANDLER=Field, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:3c794447-49bc-4b47-9e60-eead8d6aa715, timestamp=1489054627979}]
2017-03-15 11:30:40.166 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.endpoint.PollingConsumer           : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=uk.gov.ons.ctp.response.action.message.instruction.ActionInstruction@1d71b5e7, headers={jms_destination=RMQDestination{destinationName='Action.Field', queue(permanent)', amqpExchangeName='jms.durable.queues', amqpRoutingKey='Action.Field', amqpQueueName='Action.Field'}, X-Message-Sent=true, messageSent=true, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1489053876220, spanTraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, spanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, id=fc05c4e2-5c8c-783b-ccbc-e9f46d662ff7, HANDLER=Field, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:3c794447-49bc-4b47-9e60-eead8d6aa715, timestamp=1489054627979}]
2017-03-15 11:30:40.166 DEBUG [DRSGatewaySvc,,,]  20634 --- [mTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6e821210] (actionInstructionReceiverImpl.processInstruction.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=uk.gov.ons.ctp.response.action.message.instruction.ActionInstruction@1d71b5e7, headers={jms_destination=RMQDestination{destinationName='Action.Field', queue(permanent)', amqpExchangeName='jms.durable.queues', amqpRoutingKey='Action.Field', amqpQueueName='Action.Field'}, X-Message-Sent=true, messageSent=true, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1489053876220, spanTraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, spanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, jms_redelivered=false, X-B3-SpanId=18a59ce043b47b3c, X-B3-Sampled=0, X-B3-TraceId=8d176bdcbb9b1ace, id=fc05c4e2-5c8c-783b-ccbc-e9f46d662ff7, HANDLER=Field, spanSampled=0, jms_messageId=ID:3c794447-49bc-4b47-9e60-eead8d6aa715, timestamp=1489054627979}]
```

It would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

From my application.yml and the CustomPeriodicTrigger, you can see that I have got 3 passive periods during which I do NOT want the ServiceActivator to process: 00:01-08:30, 12:09-13:30 and 21:00-23:59.  If I start my app at 12:00, it will process until 12:09 and then it does NOT stop despite nextExecutionTime in CustomPeriodicTrigger = 13:30 when executed at 12:09. Now if I start my app at 12:30, I can see the same log entry saying nextExecutionTime in CustomPeriodicTrigger = 13:30. AND, it does work correctly as no processing is done until 13:30. I do not understand why in the 1st scenario, my custom perioridic trigger is being ignored.

I have put together a sample project to help replicate the issue. See https://github.com/pilif42/projectTotestTaskExecutorPauses . The README contains notes explaining how to replicate.

Comment: I call a passive period a time during which I do NOT want my ServiceActivator to process. If passive period = 2pm to 3pm. I start my app at 1.45pm. It will process until 2pm and then it does NOT stop despite nextExecutionTime in CustomPeriodicTrigger = 3pm when executed at 2pm. Now if I start my app at 2.10pm, I can see the same log entry saying nextExecutionTime in CustomPeriodicTrigger = 3pm. AND, it does work correctly as no processing is done until 3pm. I do not understand why in the 1st scenario, my custom periorid trigger is being ignored.

Comment: Please, move this to the question. You can simply edit it. Looks like it is useful info, although I'm barely understand what do you want from us?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the configuration of my ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to the below:

```
<bean id="customTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="2" />
</bean>
```

I can see that the process is paused correctly once the length of the queue (value 2) is consumed.

However, I get my logs filled in with the below. It makes sense as the queue is at maximum capacity and can't accept any more message. Should these ERRORs be at WARN instead?:

```
    2017-03-21 12:16:00.002 ERROR [projectTotestTaskExecutorPauses,83e9d055613437a4,83e9d055613437a4,false]  16069 --- [ask-scheduler-9] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@77f8a1a8[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 1]] did not accept task: org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@61c0532b
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@61c0532b rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@77f8a1a8[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 2, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:293)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You can configure `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for the `CallerRunsPolicy`. BTW, is that a solution for your problem? Was I correct that your executor continues to drain its queue with tasks even if your poller is in idle?

Comment: You were correct: the poller was correctly idle. As I had not specified a queue capacity, it was defaulting to Max.Integer and the executor was simply consuming its queue.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on CallerRunsPolicy. Having read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html , I think it will solve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention you have there `max-messages-per-poll="${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}"`. So, if there are messages in the queue for that number they will be processed during one scheduled task.

And that is correct if there is no messages, the poller will move to the `nextExecutionTime` and go to sleep.

Try to make it like `1`, at least for experimenting, to figure out how it works.

And that would be helpful to see the code of your `CustomPeriodicTrigger`.

**UPDATE**

Your problem might that there is not enough `${container.threads}` for the customTaskExecutor and many tasks are stored in the internal queue. When your trigger stops to poll, those tasks come to the scene for their job...

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified that my poller.maxMessagesPerPoll is at 1. I will add the CustomPeriodicTrigger code to the question.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem somewhere in your custom trigger. I wonder if the time for the `12:09` is treated as `00:09` and therefore when you start your app at `12:00` it see the next stop only as `00:09`.

Comment: I do not think the root cause is this as in both cases, I could see in my logs: result is 13:30.... and then no more output from the CustomPeriodicTrigger until 1.30pm. Tomorrow, I will put together a sample project in github to replicate and post again when it is ready.

Comment: That would be great! Because it isn't possible to have one date, but trigger an action for another.

Comment: I have now edited the question with a reference to the github project. Thanks in advance for your time on this issue.

Comment: Weren't you really to come up with much simpler sampler? That is really so complex application to follow up... I'll try to run it, but that is so much work to setup everything for reproducing...

Comment: Actually I'm not sure why do we talk about Poller here, since we have to just test your `CustomPeriodicTrigger`. I'd be glad to help you, but need the proper code from you to play. I'm pretty sure that there is just enough to write a bunch of test for your `CustomPeriodicTrigger` and that's all.

Comment: I have now added a unit test to the CustomPeriodicTrigger to prove that it does work correctly.

Comment: OK. That's great. So, now, please, make as small application as possible to prove that it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I have simplified the CustomPeriodicTrigger. I have trimmed down the project. I have re-tested and I am getting the same issue: see project README for details. If you have RabbitMQ installed, you should be able to build the project and run the test detailed in the section 'To replicate the issue'.

Comment: Just corrected the CustomPeriodicTrigger as I spotted an issue with it during my testing. The 'not pausing' issue is still there though as you can see in my updated README.

Comment: Sorry, your project is still very big. And sorry, I'm not going to send message to the RabbitMQ manually. If that would be just short test-case, I'd be glad to dig. Maybe your problem that there is not enough `${container.threads}` for the `customTaskExecutor` and many tasks are stored in the internal queue. When your trigger stops to poll those tasks come to the scene for their job?

Comment: I have added an answer to my question. There are though some ERROR log entries which should be at WARN I think.